# How to display a sortedlist' key n values in listbox or something else ? C#

Tags: c#, forms, interpolation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjH7l.png)

I'am working on my graduating project. I need to form a lineer interpolation programming or I will be failed. The interpolation that will be used for power plant will be easy.  So, I got a little advanced but I have a problem that how to display a sortedlist' key n values in listbox or something else ? in C#.

the codes:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var knownPairsXY = new SortedList<int, int>() 
            {
                {0, 0},
                {30, 35},
                {70, 90 },
                {100, 130}
            };

            // Input keys(x) for predicting a value(y) pairs
            var forecastKeys = new List<int> { 10,20,30}; 

            // Ensuring interpolation
            
            var avgX = knownPairsXY.Keys.Average(); 
            var avgY = knownPairsXY.Values.Average(); 

            var level = SlopeLevel(knownPairsXY); 

            foreach (var forecastKey in forecastKeys) 
            {
                // Calculating predicted value
                var predictedValue = (avgY - level * avgX) + level * forecastKey; 
                knownPairsXY.Add(forecastKey, (int)Math.Round(predictedValue)); 
            }

           
            
                listBox1.Items.Add(knownPairsXY.Values.Sort());

            




        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculates the slope level for given values
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="knownPairsXY"> The known x and y values </param>
        /// <returns> Slope level </returns>
        private static double SlopeLevel(SortedList<int, int> knownPairsXY)
        {
            var top = 0.0;
            var bottom = 0.0;

            var avgX = knownPairsXY.Keys.Average();
            var avgY = knownPairsXY.Values.Average();

            // Calculating top and bottom bound
            for (var i = 0; i < knownPairsXY.Count; i++)
            {
                top += (knownPairsXY.Keys[i] - avgX) * (knownPairsXY.Values[i] - avgY);
                bottom += Math.Pow((knownPairsXY.Keys[i] - avgX), 2);
            }

            return top / bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only sort by one thing at a time - Key or Value? which one is it?

Comment: I wrote the values which will be interpolate therefore I need to results so values ?

Comment: Depending upon the type of collection knownPairsXY is - you will have -- knownPairsXY.Values.Sort()

Comment: Please post your code.  Posting pictures of code is bad form on this site (think about someone who wants to answer your question - he/she likely wants to start from your existing code, and copying text from a picture doesn't work)

Comment: I need to list ? how can I use that ? I'm trying to solve how to progress a code block which another one's wrote. If I access the values of sorted lists values. Maybe I can handle it

Comment: @Flydog57 U r right

Comment: Iam sorry for my inexperiences

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Normally, when you use linear interpolation, you take your original data (typically two or more (X-Y) points on a 2-D graph, and a new X value and use it to estimate a corresponding Y value. The general algorithm is to find the pair of points that bound the new X value, "draw a line" between them, and then lookup the Y-value that corresponds to the X-value on that line.  Generally, you don't consider the entire dataset as a line and work with an overall slope.  Here's a complicated explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what I consider linear interpolation.  I deliberately use a dataset where the actual values can be easily calculated (a simple sine wave from 0 (degrees) to 360 (degrees).  The slope of the entire dataset will be zero (since it's a sine wave).

To start, create the data:

```
//x coordinate in degrees, not radians
private static readonly SortedList<int, double> SineWave = new SortedList<int, double>
{
    {0, 0.0},
    {30, 0.5},
    {60, 0.866025},
    {90, 1.0},
    {120, 0.866025},
    {150, 0.5},
    {180, 0.0},
    {210, -0.5},
    {240, -0.866025},
    {270, -1.0},
    {300, -0.866025},
    {330, -0.5},
    {360, 0.0},
};
```

Then create a function to do the interpolation based on that data:

```
public static double InterpolatedSine(int angleInDegrees)
{
    if (angleInDegrees == 0 || angleInDegrees == 360)
    {
        return 0.0;     //hacks the edge cases to be correct
    }
    if (angleInDegrees < 0 || angleInDegrees > 360)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(angleInDegrees),"Input angle must be in range 0 to 360 inclusive");
    }

    (int angle, double sin) last = (0,0.0);
    (int angle, double sin) below = last;
    (int angle, double sin) above = last;
    foreach (var pair in SineWave)
    {
        if (pair.Key >= angleInDegrees)
        {
            below = last;
            above = (pair.Key, pair.Value);
            break;
        }

        last = (pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }

    //this is where the interpolation happens
    var result = (((double) angleInDegrees - below.angle) / (above.angle - below.angle) *
                 (above.sin - below.sin)) + below.sin;
    return result;
}
```

That code uses *Tuples* to represent a single angle/sine pair.  A loop is used to walk through the dataset, looking for the closest tuple whose angle is less than the input angle (i.e., the one *below* the input angle) and the next one, the closest *above* it.

Once it has those two pairs, it uses the standard interpolation formula to the calculation.  It uses the proportion of the distance between the *below* angle value and the input angle, relative to the `above-below` distance as a multiplier to get the how far above the below sine value the result is.  The key code is highlighted with a comment.

Finally, I wrote a simple test method:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var testValues = new List<int> { 0, 15, 25, 45, 90, 135, 225, 240, 360 };
    //var testValues = new List<int> {45, 135};
    foreach (var val in testValues)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Angle: {val}, Interpolated: {InterpolatedSine(val)}, Actual: {Math.Sin(val/360.0*2.0*Math.PI)}");
    }
}
```

The output of this is pretty much what I expected:

```
Angle: 0, Interpolated: 0, Actual: 0
Angle: 15, Interpolated: 0.25, Actual: 0.258819045102521
Angle: 25, Interpolated: 0.416666666666667, Actual: 0.422618261740699
Angle: 45, Interpolated: 0.6830125, Actual: 0.707106781186547
Angle: 90, Interpolated: 1, Actual: 1
Angle: 135, Interpolated: 0.6830125, Actual: 0.707106781186548
Angle: 225, Interpolated: -0.6830125, Actual: -0.707106781186547
Angle: 240, Interpolated: -0.866025, Actual: -0.866025403784438
Angle: 360, Interpolated: 0, Actual: -2.44921270764475E-16
```

Note that the last *Actual* value is close enough to zero to be zero.  We are dealing with *doubles* here, so close is important.

Comment: I have the values bigger than yours :/ so bigger than 360

Comment: @inwolvenstorm: Right, I just wanted to pick something where it was obvious that interpolation was between two points, and has nothing to do with the entire dataset.  I figured a sine wave was a good example.